# Xelement node remove

Tags: c#, xelement

```
<Content Client="PQRS" ContentSectionName="INTRO">
    <Files>
        <p>abcd efgh.</p>
        <p>abcdefgh<b>ijk</b>lmnopq.</p>
        <File>
            <FileName>yyyy</FileName>
            <FilePath>xxxxxx</FilePath>
        </File>
            <File>
            <FileName>zzzz</FileName>
            <FilePath>xxxxxxyyyyy</FilePath>
        </File>
    </Files>
</Content>
```

Above Content is an Xelement.Value and want to remove every paragraph "p" node in the XElement.

Answer (score 1):

You can, for example, get all the `p` nodes in that element and just [`Remove()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.remove(v=vs.110).aspx) them:

```
var pNodes = element.Descendants("p").ToList();
foreach(var n in pNodes)
{
    n.Remove();         
}
```